# Java StringToNUMBER - return 0 if the string contains anything other than digits and an initial "-" for negative numbers

Tags: java, string

I have to implement the following function in Java: public int stringToNumber(String input) without using Integer or any other class or method that parses the string. I have to loop over the characters of the string.

I attempted created a class that uses a loop to convert String to Integer.

Now, I am trying to figure out how I can return 0 if the string contains anything other than digits and an initial "-" for negative numbers.

Also I am trying to return 0 if the number is too large or too small for an int (Integer.MIN_SIZE to Integer.MAX_SIZE or -2^31 to 2^31 - 1).

Below is the code that I have so far.... Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public class StringToNumber {


public static void main(String[] args) {
StringToNumber stn = new StringToNumber();
for (String arg : args) {
  int number = stn.stringToNumber(arg);
  System.out.format("Input number: %s, parsed number: %d %n", arg, number);
} 
}

public int stringToNumber(String stn) {
  int number = 0, factor = 1;
  for (int n = stn.length()-1; n >= 0; n--) {
      number += (stn.charAt(n) - '0') * factor;
      factor *= 10;
     }

  return number;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if below code is working for you

```
public int stringToNumber(String stn) {
              int number = 0, factor = 1;
              int negative = 0;
              if(stn.charAt(0)=='-') {
                  negative =1;
              }
              for (int n = negative; n < stn.length(); n++) {
                  int digit = stn.charAt(n)-'0';
                  if(digit<0 || digit>9)
                      return 0;
                  if((negative==0) && (Integer.MAX_VALUE-digit)/10 <number) 
                      return 0;
                  else if ((negative==1) && (Integer.MAX_VALUE-digit+1)/10 <number) 
                      return 0;
                  number = number*10+ (stn.charAt(n)-'0');
                 }

              if(negative == 1) {
                  return -1*number;
              }
              return number;
            }
```

Comment: Awesome! Your code worked for me! I only got an error because the variable factor wasn't being used. I took it out and everything is working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to handle this would be to use [`Integer#parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)), which takes a string input and either returns an integer result or throws an exception if the input cannot be coerced to an integer:

```
public int stringToNumber(String stn) {
    int result;
    try {
        result = Integer.parseInt(stn);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("String input cannot be converted to integer: " + stn);
        result = 0;   // return 0 as the failure value
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's definitely the best way to do it... but I had to implement the following function in Java: public int stringToNumber(String input) without using Integer or any other class or method that parses the string.